# Emulator browser unable to open youtube videos

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am novice to android. I am trying a application in which I try to open you-tube embed videos in web-view. But firstly , I try to open any youtube video from youtube site itself  in browser of emulator then it fails to open video and showing **Alert-dialogue** with title **Cannot play video** and msg **Sorry,this video cannot be played.** Is there any requirement of settings in emulator. Anyone has idea.

Comment: In my emulator youtube videos are running fine....
I am using android-2.3.1.Which version r u using?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am using 2.2 froyo version.

Comment: wait i'll also check for it....

Comment: In my 2.2 emulator videos are running but very very very slow and some times video hangs the emulator...

Comment: Is there any player installed in your emulator or anything?

Comment: I think suleman is write u should upgrade ur app from 2.2 to 2.3 so that u'll get better performance with videos.

Answer (score 1):

Flash player works in android only after version 2.3... Better update your device version to 2.3 or later. Then you can play youtube videos in your emulator.